# Nodah BiYhudah and "LeShem Yichud"

Tags: halacha, posek-psak-decisor-ruling

Source: http://onthemainline.blogspot.com/2010/08/jewish-oath-in-1737-part-ii-noda.html

Near the end of the post, the author mentions a teshuvah of the Nodah BiYhudah's against the saying of a *leshem yichud* (a short prefatory piece highlighting the unity of G-d).

What was the context of this question and what was his rationale? (I'd read myself, but it's nearly illegible in the scan)

Comment: I read what is posted, however it doesn't really answer the question, a more in-depth exploration would be preferred

Comment: See page 1 of [this source sheet](http://www.yutorah.org/_materials/I_Think_Therefore_I_Am-Yotze-_SOURCES-516775.pdf), where you'll find the *t'shuva* printed legibly.

Comment: "highlighting the unity of G-d" It speaks of _unifying_ God. Sounds more like it highlights His current disunity.

Comment: @DoubleAA, What would I know of lishmei yichud? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37284/leaving-the-room-during-a-kabbalistic-dvar-torah

Comment: @DoubleAA Presumably, advocates of this practice would say that *mitzvos* unite the manifestation of HaShem's name in this world, along the lines of [*Z'charya* 14:9](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2314.htm#9) and along the lines of the *Tanchuma* ([*Ki Seitzei* 11](http://www.tsel.org/torah/tanhuma/kitetsa.html)): רבי לוי בשם רבי אחא ברבי חיננא אומר, כל זמן שזרעו של עמלק בעולם, לא השם שלם, ולא הכסא שלם. אבד זרעו של עמלק, השם שלם והכסא שלם. Neither of those sources implies that HaShem Himself is divided.

Comment: @Fred Yes, but MiMaNafshach it isn't talking about the unity of God.

Answer (score 3):

The context of the question was what is the correct way to say *l'shem yichud*, and the response was that maybe it isn't such a good idea to say it at all.

Regarding the rationale, someone who knows these things better than I explained it in terms that I think are understandable:

If you have your Microsoft operating system with its factory settings, your computer will work just fine.  If you start playing around with the settings, you could customize your computer, or, if you don't know what you are doing, you could mess everything up.

When we *daven* or do *mitzvos* "regularly_, there is a built in status-quo put into the *berachos* by the *anshei knesses hagedola*.  When you decide to direct it on your own, if you don't really understand what you are doing, you will make things much worse.

Comment: You've invited a great machloket, Microsoft won't always work fine with the factory settings (source: personal experience)

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt I chose Microsoft because Linux is meant to be tweaked and Microsoft isn't.

Comment: I am a lifelong Apple user, although I have run Windows in the past when necessary

Comment: Is that the _Noda Bihuda_'s rationale or just a rationale?

Comment: @msh210 the _Noda B'Yehuda_'s.